# Managed VCL.Arrow keys and Tab key

Tags: c#, delphi, keyboard-events

I'm using Managed VCL to host my .net User control on Delphi form.
But I have a problem: tab key,arrow keys and specific keys(HOME,INSERT) don't work.


**I tried everything which was written on Managed VCL forum.**

1)I tried to put my user control to a higher level user control and override ProcessDialogKey there.But this didn't help.

2)I tried to add  DLGC_WANTTAB or  DLGC_WANTALLKEYS to Message Result of TClrCustomControl.WMGetDlgCode,but this also didn't help me.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I solved it by intercepting the tab key on the host form and not allowing it to handle the keystroke.  The following code worked in my case:

```pascal
procedure CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey); message CM_DIALOGKEY;
...
procedure TForm1.CMDialogKey(var Message: TCMDialogKey);
begin
  if Message.CharCode = VK_TAB then
    // ignore tabs and allow the TClrControl to handle them
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

In my case, the TClrControl is client aligned and covers the entire form, so this may not be quite right in your situation if you are mixing VCL and .NET controls.